# Index.html returning 404 in tomcat when accessed directly

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I installed tomcat. Root folder is /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT which has a index.html file. this file can be accessed as *server-ip:8080* . But  *server-ip:8080/index.html* returns 404 . Why may this be?

Comment: Is it definitely `index.html` in the root folder and not `index.jsp`?

Comment: It is index.html alright

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that when your server's serving from your web.xml's welcome-file-list (usually specified as something like this:)

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

it has different permissions than when you try to navigate to it directly.